# RDP to Windows 2003 results in Blank screen

Tags: windows-server-2003, rdp

When I try to RDP to a Windows 2003 server, sometimes after I enter the login credentials, I see the background color of the desktop, but no icons, and no taskbar.  Sometimes disconnecting from RDP, and then reconnecting solves it, but I don't see any issues in the Event Logs.
I know the machine is up, as it presents the login screen, and if I put a bad password, or a user name that does not have the rights to login remotely, it tells me.  But when I put a good password in, it just hangs on the background.

Any Ideas on what to check?

TIA

Comment: Have you checked the issues here http://support.microsoft.com/kb/555840?

Comment: @Zoredache - Yes, I've tried disabling the BitMap cacheing with no success.  I have not played with the MTU on the Server, but its the W2K3 default.  I don't suspect the switch/router, as I can connect to other servers on the subnet.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I've seen this happen when you don't have a clean log off of your previous session. If you log onto the console and check the RDP connected users do you have an entry there for your user? If so kick it off the RDP session and try logging in again.

Comment: Yep, I've seen this when a logoff doesn't complete for whatever reason (in my experience, usually profile issues).  You can safely kill the session from the RDP MMC Console.

Comment: There WAS a disconnected session.  I killed it an will see if the problem goes away...

Comment: Worked for me: Administrative Tools->Terminal Services Manager.